# Guava Cache: Put operation triggers removal listener

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

I have a cache and am putting new elements into it. Every time I put an item in the cache the removal listener gets triggered. How do I get the removal listener to be triggered only when things are actually being removed or evicted?

```
Cache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
//      .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .removalListener((RemovalListener<String, String>) notification -> {
        System.out.println("Why");
    })
    .build();
}

cache.put("a","b"); // triggers removal listener
```

Am I missing something here? Why isn't it called a `PutListener`?

Comment: Did you check notification.getCause()?  Did you print the key and the value from the removal notification?

Comment: The keys were being replaced. I thought my keys were distinct but they weren't. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To find the actual cause the [RemovalNotification.getCause() method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/RemovalNotification.html#getCause--) should be used.

To handle all the event notifications, except the «Replaced entry» event notification, please consider the following draft implementation:

```
class RemovalListenerImpl implements RemovalListener<String, String> {
    @Override
    public void onRemoval(final RemovalNotification<String, String> notification) {
        if (RemovalCause.REPLACED.equals(notification.getCause())) {
            // Ignore the «Entry replaced» event notification.
            return;
        }

        // TODO: Handle the event notification here.
    }
}
```